# logistic regression R prediction function

Tags: r, statistics

I have a glm model and use the following script:

`prob=predict(myglm,type=("response"))`

If i export this prob vector i get 1 column with all the probabilities.

```
prob=predict(myglm,type=("terms"))
```

This will provide me the terms for each observation in my data set.

My question is how can I export the data set with the
response probability column added to the end of the file?

Thanks is advance!

Comment: Have no idea what you asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is all you want to add a column with the predicted probability to the dataframe used to build the model? If so you do it this way:

```
mydata$prob <- predict(myglm, type = "response")
```

Please read [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) to learn the basics of the R language, it is the standard tutorial.